# Error 302 Downloading File in Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

Why am I receiving this error?

```
[scrapy] WARNING: File (code: 302): Error downloading file from <GET <url> referred in <None>
```

The URL seems to download without any problems in my browser and a 302 is simply a redirect. Why wouldn't scrapy simply follow the redirect to download the file?

```
process = CrawlerProcess({
    'FILES_STORE': 'C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\Scrapy',
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)',
    'ITEM_PIPELINES': {'scrapy.pipelines.files.FilesPipeline': 1},
})

process.crawl(MySpider)
process.start()  # the script will block here until the crawling is finished
```

Comment: Try a different user-agent, here my browsers: `Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36`

Comment: The user agent is not working. I suspect something is wrong with the donwloader middlewares, because I was able to download the files using a scrapy.Request. I am investigating further.

Comment: Okay, so far what I have found is that `request.meta.get('handle_httpstatus_all', False)` returns true in the downloader middleware.

Answer (score 4):

My solution is use requests to send a http requests first,base on the status_code to choose which url to download, now you can put the url in file_urls or your custom name.

```
import requests

def check_redirect(url):
    response = requests.head(url)
    if response.status_code == 302:
        url = response.headers["Location"]
    return url
```

or may be you can use custom filespipeline

```
class MyFilesPipeline(FilesPipeline):

def handle_redirect(self, file_url):
    response = requests.head(file_url)
    if response.status_code == 302:
        file_url = response.headers["Location"]
    return file_url

def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
    redirect_url = self.handle_redirect(item["file_urls"][0])
    yield scrapy.Request(redirect_url)

def item_completed(self, results, item, info):
    file_paths = [x['path'] for ok, x in results if ok]
    if not file_paths:
        raise DropItem("Item contains no images")
    item['file_urls'] = file_paths
    return item
```

I used other solution here [Scrapy i/o block when downloading files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38800942/scrapy-i-o-block-when-downloading-files)

Answer (score 4):

If redirection is the problem you should add following, in your **settings.py** :

```
MEDIA_ALLOW_REDIRECTS = True
```

Source : [Allowing redirections
 in Scrapy](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html#allowing-redirections)

Answer (score 3):

The root of the problem seems to be this code in `pipelines/media.py`:

```
   def _check_media_to_download(self, result, request, info):
        if result is not None:
            return result
        if self.download_func:
            # this ugly code was left only to support tests. TODO: remove
            dfd = mustbe_deferred(self.download_func, request, info.spider)
            dfd.addCallbacks(
                callback=self.media_downloaded, callbackArgs=(request, info),
                errback=self.media_failed, errbackArgs=(request, info))
        else:
            request.meta['handle_httpstatus_all'] = True
            dfd = self.crawler.engine.download(request, info.spider)
            dfd.addCallbacks(
                callback=self.media_downloaded, callbackArgs=(request, info),
                errback=self.media_failed, errbackArgs=(request, info))
        return dfd
```

Specifically, the line that sets `handle_httpstatus_all` to `True` disables the redirect middleware for the download, which triggers the error. I will ask on the scrapy github for the reasons for this.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for figuring this out! Any updates on this issue?